# Send/Add CVV/CVN Field on Cybersource Flex Microform

Tags: salesforce, cybersource

I am using Flex Microform and was able to successfully render the Credit Card Iframe from Cybersource.

Now, the question is to `Add`/`Send` `CVN`/`CVV` details along with above request.

In the document, we can pass only three parameters in the `createToken` Method - `CardType`, `CardExpirationYear`, and `CardExpirationMonth`.

I couldn't find anything about sending/Adding CVN.

Please guide if anyone has done similar implementation where we can send CVN details from the Flex Form.

Comment: this my help you : https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-flex/da-microform-integ/microform-integ/api_reference/class_microform.html

Comment: @Tech Any reference code how to rendered Cybersource Credit Card Iframe in UI code/page ?

Answer (score 0):

Html

```
        --- 
        <label id="cardNumber-label">Card Number</label>
        <div id="number-container" class="form-control"></div>

        <label for="securityCode-container">Security Code</label>
        <div id="securityCode-container" class="form-control"></div>

        --
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        ----

</form>
```

Js

```
var flex = new Flex(captureContext);
var microform = flex.microform({ styles: myStyles });
var number = microform.createField('number', { placeholder: 'Enter card number' });

var securityCode = microform.createField('securityCode', { placeholder: '•••' });

number.load('#number-container');
securityCode.load('#securityCode-container');
```

Ref: [developer-guides](https://developer.cybersource.com/api/developer-guides/dita-flex/da-microform-integ/microform-integ/api_reference/class_microform.html)

Comment: Any reference how to render Cybersource Credit Card iframe layout in Angular/Html/.Net Code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for
https://developer.cybersource.com/docs/cybs/en-us/digital-accept-flex/developer/all/rest/digital-accept-flex/microform-integ/api_reference/class_Microform.html

Example:

```html
<div class="container card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h1>Checkout</h1>
    <div id="errors-output" role="alert"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="cardholderName">Name</label>
      <input id="cardholderName" class="form-control" name="cardholderName" placeholder="Name on the card">
      <label id="cardNumber-label">Card Number</label>

      <div id="number-container" class="form-control"></div>
      <label for="securityCode-container">Security Code</label>
      <div id="securityCode-container" class="form-control"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="expMonth">Expiry month</label>
        <select id="expMonth" class="form-control">
          <option>01</option>
          <option>02</option>
          <option>03</option>
          <option>04</option>
          <option>05</option>
          <option>06</option>
          <option>07</option>
          <option>08</option>
          <option>09</option>
          <option>10</option>
          <option>11</option>
          <option>12</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="expYear">Expiry year</label>
        <select id="expYear" class="form-control">
          <option>2022</option>
          <option>2023</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<script src="https://flex.cybersource.com/cybersource/assets/microform/0.11/flex-microform.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#submission-form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    var form = document.querySelector('#submission-form');
    var payButton = document.querySelector('#btnPay');
    var flexResponse = document.querySelector('#SecureToken');
    var expMonth = document.querySelector('#expMonth');
    var expYear = document.querySelector('#expYear');
    var errorsOutput = document.querySelector('#errors-output');

    // the capture context that was requested server-side for this transaction
    var captureContext = /*caputre context loaded here*/ ;

    // setup
    var flex = new Flex(captureContext);
    var number = microform.createField('number', {
      placeholder: 'Enter card number'
    });
    var securityCode = microform.createField('securityCode', {
      placeholder: '•••'
    });

    number.load('#number-container');

    securityCode.load('#securityCode-container');

    payButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
      var options = {
        expirationMonth: expMonth.value,
        expirationYear: expYear.value
      };

      microform.createToken(options, function(err, token) {
        if (err) {
          // handle error
        } else {
          flexResponse.value = JSON.stringify(token);
          form.submit();
        }
      });
    });

  });
</script>
```